# list_filters are not working with redefined get_queryset in Admin list_view if that contains union

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-queryset, django-admin-filters

I needed to create Django Admin `list_view` page with redefined `get_queryset()` method that will do union by different models to the same page.
But after I updated it, `list_filter` stopped work.

As I find out if you use [`union()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.union) - Django doesn't allow to do any further filtering (only `LIMIT`, `OFFSET`, `COUNT(*)`, `ORDER BY` SQL operations).
And for some reason application of these filters is implemented after call of `get_queryset()`. I thought that call `super().get_queryset(request)` in my `ModelAdmin.get_queryset()` will return already parsed data.

**UPD:** In this situation no filters working and queryset in actions always contain all model records, even if few selected just a few.

```py
class Model1():
    pass


class ModelA():
    x = models.ForeignKey(Model1)


class ModelB():
    x = models.ForeignKey(Model1)


class Model1Admin():
    list_display = (...)
    list_filters = (...)  # These will not work
    list_actions = (...)  # These will not work

    def get_queryset():
        qs_a = Model1.prefetch_related('ModelA')
        qs_b = Model1.prefetch_related('ModelB')
        return qs_a.union(qs_b)
```

Questions:

1. Is there any simple way how to get queryset with already applied `list_filters` and after do my custom filtering and union?
2. Is this a bug in Django Framework by itself and this should be reported in their bug-tracker?

Comment: The admin pages are designed to work with single models so I wouldn't say it's a bug. Can you create a view for this page instead?

Comment: I would create the whole "Union" query as an sql view, then with the resulting Django model you do can whatever you want using filters.

Comment: @elsadek is there the “sql view” for admin app?

Comment: @IainShelvington I need to have a report as a part of Admin app.

Comment: @wowkin2 you can create a model as well as AdminModel for database views

Comment: @elsadek I already created a proxy model. And this proxy model does annotation by other models and union to join results together.

Comment: @wowkin2 that's exactly what you should avoid, create a database view that has all the joins and unions, and map a new model to that view.

Comment: @elsadek, actually I have the `Model1 Model1Admin` with custom `get_queryset()`, that returns `Model1.prefetch_related('ModelA').union(Model1.prefetch_related('ModelB'))`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @wowkin2 if you create a database view, you will unlikely need to override `get_queryset`, hence that `union` should reside in this view.

Comment: @elsadek I provided an example of what I currently use. Let me know if you mean something else.

Comment: @wowkin2 create `Model_1_A_B` that maps to the database view, that view joins/union `table_1` with `table_A` and `table_B`, and `Model_1_A_B` returns the queryset on which you want to apply those filters.